# Trigger created with compilation errors that cannot be found?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, syntax-error, plsqldeveloper

Using a combination of a *TRIGGER FUNCTION* to automatically monitor the minimum stock levels in order to trigger a reminder message.

This is a learning exercise and have tried changing it using all the help from stackoverflow but does not seem to want to work still.

The following Syntax was created:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER STOCKqtyCheck
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF QTY ON STOCK
DECLARE

    MINIMUM_QTY NUMBER 
    QTY NUMBER
    STOCK_LOW_Error EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    SELECT count(*)
    /* THE COUNT WILL LOOK INTO QTY */
    INTO QTY    
    FROM STOCK.MINIMUM_QTY
    WHERE
    /* WHERE MINIMUM QTY IS LESS THAN QTY */
    'MINIMUM_QTY' <= 'QTY' 
    IF STOCK_LOW_Error < 'MINIMUM_QTY' THEN
    RAISE STOCK_LOW_Error;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN STOCK_LOW_Error THEN
        Raise_Application_Error ('STOCK LEVEL TO LOW Error'));
END;
/
```

**SQL Output:**

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER STOCKqtyCheck
  2  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF QTY ON STOCK
  3  
  4  DECLARE
  5   
  6   MINIMUM_QTY NUMBER 
  7   QTY NUMBER
  8   STOCK_LOW_Error EXCEPTION;
  9  
 10  BEGIN
 11   SELECT count(*)
 12   /* THE COUNT WILL LOOK INTO QTY */
 13   INTO QTY 
 14   FROM STOCK.MINIMUM_QTY
 15   WHERE
 16   /* WHERE MINIMUM QTY IS LESS THAN QTY */
 17   'MINIMUM_QTY' <= 'QTY' 
 18   
 19   IF STOCK_LOW_Error < 'MINIMUM_QTY'  THEN
 20    RAISE STOCK_LOW_Error;
 21   END IF;
 22  
 23  EXCEPTION
 24   WHEN STOCK_LOW_Error THEN
 25    Raise_Application_Error ('STOCK LEVEL TO LOW Error'));
 26  END;
 27  /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
```

What are the compilation errors? I checked the tables they are there and created correctly and all the foreign keys & primary keys are there correctly too including the field data type and How could I embed the cursor below into the trigger?.

```
CURSOR Stock_count
 IS
 SELECT QTY,MINIMUM_QTY 
 FROM STOCK;
```

Comment: Does your `SELECT` query work? Seems like line 17 is incorrect. Plus, line 19 doesn't make sense too. How can an exception be less than 20? When you get compilation errors in triggers and you don't have a GUI that points out the errors, check the procedure and dry-run it in your head to see if it's syntactically and semantically correct. Also execute the `SELECT` statements and ensure they return the correct results.

Comment: @ADTC Thanks for your comment; In line 17 I'm telling it that it should refer to QTY column in Stock table to compare against the minimum on hand (Minimum_QTY) but I don't know any other way to do it. With the Exception if it is less than 20 aka minimum in sotck (I've updated the code above) in stock than cause an error as the QTY column look up does not work.

Comment: I'm going by the visible line numbers in your _SQL Output_. Anyway, about what you said: _I'm telling it that it should refer to QTY column in Stock table to compare against the minimum on hand (Minimum_QTY)_ < Did you actually execute this query and get the expected result? I suspect that you just wrote the query but never tested it before putting it in your trigger code.

Comment: @ADTC is it correct way to reference a field with :=QTY, I tried this and it seems to not pull up errors

Comment: I really think you're understanding this wrongly. _With the Exception if it is less than 20_ Again, this makes no sense. Exceptions cannot be less than any numeric value. They are just exceptions. What you need to do is check if `QTY < 20` (this _20_ should really be an externally controllable variable, not a hard-coded value inside the trigger).

Comment: I did excute it and got error complication errors to your comment 2minutes ago I didn't know until @user272735 told me about show errors trigger stockqtycheck

Comment: `Raise_Application_Error ('STOCK LEVEL TO LOW Error'));` is wrong. You put two closing brackets. Raise_Application_Error expects at least two arguments, the error-code and the message.

Comment: Well if you found the errors, then correct them. :) And btw I mean execute your `SELECT` query alone separately on an active database to see if it really returns what you think it returns. I don't mean execute the `CREATE TRIGGER` script.

Comment: `RAISE STOCK_LOW_Error;` does not work unless you defined the exception before hand, check `PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(...` in Oracle doc.

Answer (score 1):

> What are the compilation errors?

Trigger compilation errors in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> show errors trigger stockqtycheck
```

For other tools refer the tool's user manual.

At minimum you're missing several semi-colons `;`.

Answer (score 1):

The `SHOW ERRORS` command may not run in all cases. The best way, according to me, to retrieve compilation errors is as follows-

```
SELECT *
  FROM user_errors
 WHERE name = 'STOCKQTYCHECK';
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing i think is along with raise_application_error you have to associate your error message with an error number between -20000 and -20999. Please refer this link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm

or else you have to associate your user defined exception with an oracle error number using pragma_exception_init()